# How to check for domain Constraints using oleDb?

Tags: c#, oledb

I have to find every columns that doesn't have a domain constraints in a database(MS Access) and for each one calculate min and max values to the current data and then to add from my program the corresponding constraint.

For example, a column "Foo" has the min value 0 and the max value 100,and I need the constraint "Foo between 0 And 100".

How can I check if a column has this constraint in C# ?

In access I found this at "Validation rules".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace Proiect
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    private new OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.Carti'     
        this.cartiTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.Carti);
        cartiTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.Carti);
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        con.ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"+
       "DataSource=D:\..\BD.accdb";
        cmd.Connection=con; 
        this.cartiTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.Carti);
        chkC.Checked=false;

    }

    private void chkC_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

     }
    }
```

Comment: Mirela, as I was curious I have spend a fair bit of time finding the answer for your question. I'll post my answer in couple of mins for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Mehrad! Now I have to figure out how to make the program work ... I have to look for the min and max and put the corresponding constraint...You saved me!

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard. Again, if you couldn't and had problems leave a comment here and I will extend my answer to cover those point. You're more than welcome.

Comment: Ok...I have no chance to do this! I have no idea how to begin...I deleted everything and started again,but I am confused...My idee is to do a Form and put there 1 listBox  that contains the name of the tables and a button: "Add constraint" ... but i don't know how and where to display the columns that don't have domain constraint. and before that,I have to make the button work and i have to extract the min and max values and add the corresponding constraint...:((

Comment: Well well well. I hope you are eager to learn cuz seems you have some basics to tick off. If so, I'll proceed and give you some ideas and also some references to read and learn. 1st off, you need to break your project to some main chunks and do them one at a time. In this case, your homework would be to **1.**Learn how to put a button on your form and write it's `OnClick` event.**2.**Learn how to relate the data in a `List` to a `ListBox`.**3.**How to get the list of Tables` fields(See my update on the answer).(+put them in the list and feed them to `ListBox`).Do steps 1&2 I'll show you 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purpose of checking the constrains applied on your table you are looking to use [OleDbSchemaGuid.Check_Constraints Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbschemaguid.check_constraints%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). How to use this is actually a little bit different with how you would use per say `OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables`.

To help you on this I have written you a little console application that you can simply copy/paste on a new *console application project* in Visual Studio (or any preferred software) and run it to see how this works in action. The example is implemented on the famous **Northwind** database.

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

//Open a connection to the SQL Server Northwind database.
// This is the sample DB I have used in my example.
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
cn.Open();

//Retrieve records from the Employees table into a DataReader.
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees";

//Retrieve column schema into a constraints.
var schemaTable = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Check_Constraints,null);

//For each field in the table...
foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    //For each property of the field...
    foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schemaTable.Columns)
    {
        //Display the field name and value.
        Console.WriteLine(myProperty.ColumnName + " = " + myField[myProperty].ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Pause.
}
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadLine();
//Always close the DataReader and connection.
cn.Close();
```

and if you look at the output, you can see the constraint applied on the `Discount` field of `Discount` table.

```
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = Northwind
CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = dbo
CONSTRAINT_NAME = CK_Discount
CHECK_CLAUSE = ([Discount]>=(0) AND [Discount]<=(1))
DESCRIPTION =
```

**Update**

Also in general I will recommend you to get yourself familiar with [How To Retrieve Column Schema by Using the DataReader GetSchemaTable Method and Visual C# .NET](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/310107/en-us)

The example below is the line by line copy of the code from link above except I have added a `List` of `string` to this code and captured the table's field name (called `ColumnName` in C# `DataColumn` in this context), and I have marked the lines I have added with `// ++ Added ++`.

OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    DataTable schemaTable;
    OleDbDataReader myReader;

```
//Open a connection to the SQL Server Northwind database.
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=EINSTEINIUM\\SQL2014EXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
cn.Open();

//Retrieve records from the Employees table into a DataReader.
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

//Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

// ++ Added ++
var listOfTableFields = new List<string>();

//For each field in the table...
foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    //For each property of the field...
    foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schemaTable.Columns)
    {
        //Display the field name and value.
        Console.WriteLine(myProperty.ColumnName + " = " + myField[myProperty].ToString());

        // ++ Added ++
        if (myProperty.ColumnName == "ColumnName")
        {
            listOfTableFields.Add(myField[myProperty].ToString());
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Pause.
}

//Always close the DataReader and connection.
myReader.Close();
cn.Close();

// ++ Added ++
Console.WriteLine("List of fields in Employees table.");
// List of Fields in the Employees table.
foreach (var fieldName in listOfTableFields)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fieldName);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Paste this code in a Console app and learn how to use it. It will be very easy then to move the parts you need to the buttons `OnClick`.